# Decoupling channels on an oscilloscope?

Tags: signal, oscilloscope, signal-generator

I have 2 x [AD9833s programmable waveform generators](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9833.pdf) running off the same SPI bus.

Generator A is on channel 1 (yellow in the picture below) and is a sine wave set at 1 kHz.

[image]

Generator B is on channel 2 (blue in the picture below) and is a sine wave set at 2 kHz.

[image]

The outputs are as expected if I just probe each output individually but when I probe both at the same time I get...

[image]

Can someone explain what is happening here? Is there some scope-voodoo I'm unaware of?

SOLVED: I had the probe leads connected incorrectly, I had the scope grounds connected to the generator signal out & vice-versa.

Comment: Both probes share the same ground. Are you clipping the ground clips to two different nodes?

Comment: @DKNguyen the AD9833s both have an OUT & a AGND so I connected the probes to the respective OUT & AGND on each AD9833

Comment: They are on the same board running off the same power supplies?

Comment: @DKNguyen yes they are both running off the same supply

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm an idiot I have the probes the wrong way around in the outputs & grounds. Thanks for making look closer. I'll edit my post.

Comment: That'll do it..

Comment: @DrBwts Be careful with that! It looks like it was fine in this case but it's not hard to fry your oscilloscope through that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both probes share the same ground. Are you clipping the ground clips to two different nodes?